# Способы реализации индикаторов на мнемосхеме в Qt Designer

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, qt-designer

Требуется совет по реализации мнемосхемы в Qt Designer. Над QProgressBar'ами нужно расположить мнемохему, которая отображает только индикацию состояния узлов установки. Из 9 узлов, только один обладает тремя состояниями, оставшиеся - бинарные. Видел варианты, что можно добавить QGraphicsView или Opengl. Или проще будет создать свой виджет?

[image: Место, где должна расположиться мнемосхема]

Мнемосхема должна быть подобной:

[image: Примерная мнемосхема]

Comment: Мне кажется, самый просто способ через `QGraphicsView` в своем виджете

Comment: `QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene и QGraphicsSvgItem` с svg будет все просто - рисуете схему целиком и сохраняете в svg (например в inkscape'e), в ней же ноды с измененными состояниями (другим цветом, шрифтом и т.д.), которые показываете/скрываете по мере необходимости

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicssvgitem.html